Magento 2 : I can't run any command in CLI
When I try to run setup:upgrade or any other command in the terminal it says: Class "Swissup\ Core\Helper\Component" not found#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(150):
And more other things that we can see in the print
In the debug logs it says: main.CRITICAL: Error: Class “Swissup\Core\Observer\Backend\FetchNotifications” not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:121
This is what line 121 of AbstractFactory.php has:
Someone please help me I need to solve this as fast as possible, I dont know why this error happened

are you using Swiss Up Theme or any extension into system?

As per the error, the Swissup\Core library is missing. Can you verify if the same class (Swissup\ Core\Helper\Component) exists or not. If not exists then please get & install the Core library of Swissup.

how do I check if that class exists or not?

@Xerobin, solved this error or not.?

@mohitvamja go discord please
